# Strange CFFI callback error with SBCL

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, portaudio, cffi

I have this Common Lisp code which is a CFFI binding to PortAudio : https://github.com/thodg/cffi-portaudio

First time I build with ASDF it gives no warning, but if I try to reload the system it tells me about these :

```
STYLE-WARNING: Undefined alien: "Pa_GetErrorText"
STYLE-WARNING: Undefined alien: "Pa_Initialize"
STYLE-WARNING: Undefined alien: "Pa_Terminate"
STYLE-WARNING: Undefined alien: "Pa_OpenStream"
STYLE-WARNING: Undefined alien: "Pa_OpenDefaultStream"
STYLE-WARNING: Undefined alien: "Pa_CloseStream"
STYLE-WARNING: Undefined alien: "Pa_StartStream"
STYLE-WARNING: Undefined alien: "Pa_StopStream"
STYLE-WARNING: Undefined alien: "Pa_AbortStream"
STYLE-WARNING: Undefined alien: "Pa_IsStreamStopped"
STYLE-WARNING: Undefined alien: "Pa_IsStreamActive"
```

And then -- wether I load the code once or twice, it makes no difference -- if I run the TEST function it crashes SBCL with this strange message :

```
"callback" CORRUPTION WARNING in SBCL pid 3501(tid 0x7fffe0ac9700):
Received signal 8 in non-lisp thread 140736962795264, resignalling to a lisp thread.
The integrity of this image is possibly compromised.
Continuing with fingers crossed.

Process inferior-lisp floating point exception
```

There are no floats in my callback, so the error seems very strange to me.
Everything before START-STREAM seems to run properly. But then START-STREAM jumps on the callback and it crashes.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I downloaded the code and it seems to work fine on my machine : linux 64 bits, sbcl 1.3.15.12-e3f53a3, I installed portaudio19-dev via apt-get.